# What would you use for 'About', 'Help' and 'Licence' in an application?

Tags: software

What would you use for 'About', 'Help' and 'Licence' in a software application, in Mandarin?

This is such as you would find by clicking the 'Help' menu on an application.

Thank you,

L

Answer (score 1):

About: 關於我們

Help: 幫助支持

Licence: 服務條款

I just copied it from a Chinese website iTalkBB. Other sites may use different terms

For example

幫助支持 --> 支援

關於我們 --> 關於

服務條款 -->使用條款

Comment: Thanks. It seems in English, (and Chinese, as it seems from your answer), 'Terms of Service' / 服務條款 is common on webpages. They would be different to software sometimes though. 幫助 seems an option for Help, though I also found 説明, as above. For 'About', I found  關於 /关于, the same as you have.

Answer (score 0):

I thought to try Chinese language on software I have already installed.

Help: 説明 (tw), but 帮助 (cn).

About: 關於 /关于 .

Licence:

- 公共授權 / 公共授权 , but this was a GPL application, and it seems only GNU use this term.
- Mozilla uses 許可證 / 许可证 (and 授權 / 授权)
- Creative Commons uses 授權 / 授权.

I'm not sure which of these words for licence would be most appropriate. Perhaps not the first one, for the reasons above.

Comment: GNU General *Public License* is where 公共授权 comes from; 公共 = Public. Mainland Chinese law on software IP protection explicitly refers to 使用许可.

Comment: I'll use "使用許可 (= 授權 / 授权), or simply 許可. 證,(certificate) is dropped because you are likely to post the copy of it, but list the source of permission and the number of the certificate.